# Error => Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

`Hello, EveryOne`

I'm Learning ReactJs.

I'm getting this error whenever I upadate isOpen state.

error : Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

`here is code`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { slide as Menu } from "react-burger-menu";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import "./SideBar.css";

const withLocation = (SideBar) => (props) => {
    const location = useLocation();
    return true ? <SideBar {...props} location={location} /> : "";
};

const SideBar = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);

    const location = useLocation();
    const homeClass = location.pathname === "/" ? "active-item" : "";
    const aboutClass = location.pathname === "/about" ? "active-item" : "";
    const projectClass = location.pathname === "/projects" ? "active-item" : "";
    const skillsClass = location.pathname === "/skills" ? "active-item" : "";
    const contactClass = location.pathname === "/contact" ? "active-item" : "";
    
    return (
        <Menu isOpen={isOpen}>
            <Link
                to='/'
                onClick={setIsOpen(false)}
                className={`menu-item ${homeClass}`}>
                Home
            </Link>
            <Link to='/about' className={`menu-item ${aboutClass}`}>
                About
            </Link>
            <Link to='/projects' className={`menu-item ${projectClass}`}>
                Projects
            </Link>
            <Link to='/skills' className={`menu-item ${skillsClass}`}>
                Skills
            </Link>
            <Link to='/contact' className={`menu-item ${contactClass}`}>
                Contact
            </Link>
        </Menu>
    );
};
export default withLocation(SideBar);
```

I don't  know how to solve this Problem.

Comment: `onClick={setIsOpen(false)}` You're calling `setIsOpen(false)` *immediately*, not when the click happens. Change it to: `onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}`

Answer (score 0):

`onClick={setIsOpen(false)}` will be calling everytime you render your page. Setting a state will render your page too. What that mean is you are creating infinite loop.

```
onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}
```

will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your button that fires the setState immediately causing too many re-renders,

Replace

```
       <Link
            to='/'
            onClick={setIsOpen(false)}
            className={`menu-item ${homeClass}`}>
            Home
      </Link>
```

To

```
       <Link
            to='/'
            onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}
            className={`menu-item ${homeClass}`}>
            Home
      </Link>
```

if you want to read about more solutions check out this [article](https://www.datainfinities.com/20/too-many-re-renders-react-limits-the-number-of-renders-to-prevent-an-infinite-loop)

Answer (score 0):

change your code on `Link` as

```
       <Link
          to='/'
          onClick={()=>setIsOpen(false)}
          className={`menu-item ${homeClass}`}>
```

when we call a function directly without arrow function, it calls automatically when it renders first time. and are using `setState` in in that function so component re-renders after executing first time and then again and again because of state update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
onClick={setIsOpen(false)}
```

When setting attributes like this the code inside the brackets is executed during rendering and the value of the attribute is set to the result.

When calling `setIsOpen` the state is updated and this triggers a new render, which in turn callse `setIsOpen` again and triggers another render etc.

What you want is the set the onClick handler to the function that should run when the link is clicked, to do that you should do this:

```
onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}
```

This will not call `setIsOpen` untill the link is clicked. As executing the code inside the brackets will not actually call `setIsOpen` but instead returns a function that will call `setIsOpen` when the function is called.

Setting handlers can be a bit confusing at first, but remember that when setting handlers like this you want to set the value to a function and not the result of calling the function.